# Apache Druid – Ingesting multiple objects in flat JSON data returns only single row

Tags: json, list, jq, jsonpath, druid

**I'm aiming to ingest this JSON data into Apache Druid as multiple rows.** The data (about 10x more rows than this example) is served from a proprietary HTTP server that I have no control over. I cannot change how the data is presented from the HTTP server. The data will be pulled periodically, as there is no notification from the HTTP server.

```
{
  "1": {
    "lastseen": "2021-02-15T05:02Z",
    "name": "Temperature Sensor A",
    "state": {
      "alert": "none",
      "level": 152,
      "on": true,
      "reachable": true
    }
  },
  "3": {
    "lastseen": "2021-02-15T05:01Z",
    "name": "Temperature Sensor B",
    "state": {
      "alert": "none",
      "level": 13,
      "on": false,
      "reachable": true
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "lastseen": "2021-02-15T05:00Z",
    "name": "Temperature Sensor Backup",
    "state": {
      "alert": "none",
      "level": 76,
      "on": true,
      "reachable": true
    }
  }
}
```

Note that object 2 is missing. This number is an internal record ID from the server, and if object 2 is deleted, this ID will disappear from subsequent requests.

I have created a data source that successfully pulls the data, but it ends up as as single row. As I understand, since the JSON object has no array at the root level, Druid sees these three objects as a single row.

I suspect that the answer lies somewhere in the [`flattenSpec`](https://druid.apache.org/docs/0.19.0/ingestion/data-formats.html#flattenspec) area, but I have failed to get this going. The closest I have gotten so far is with the following `flattenSpec`, but this only returns the first row from the JSON data (though the row is represented correctly).

```
  "inputFormat": {
    "type": "json",
    "flattenSpec": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "jq",
          "expr": ".[].name",
          "name": "name"
        },
        {
          "type": "jq",
          "expr": ".[].lastseen",
          "name": "lastseen"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The above `flattenSpec` gives me a single row that looks like:

```
lastseen              | name
2021-02-15T05:02Z     | Temperature Sensor A
```

**How can I get Druid to see all the rows?** What is the right flattenSpec (or jq / JSONPath expression)?

I am not concerned about performance, but I would prefer not to have to spin up more proxy-like services between the HTTP server and Druid.

Comment: At this moment, it's not possible using the flattenSpec.

Answer (score 0):

Try a filter like this and no flattening should be required:

```
jq '.[] | {name,lastseen}'
```

Using your input, this results in:

```
{
  "name": "Temperature Sensor A",
  "lastseen": "2021-02-15T05:02Z"
}
{
  "name": "Temperature Sensor B",
  "lastseen": "2021-02-15T05:01Z"
}
{
  "name": "Temperature Sensor Backup",
  "lastseen": "2021-02-15T05:00Z"
}
```

Comment: Using the jq library on its own, that filter would surely do the job. However, this issue pertains to the particulars of Apache Druid, which apparently has limited or no support for applying filters on the data set before parsing. Would you know where in the Apache Druid ingestion parsing spec this filter might be applied?

Comment: I contributed the jq support to Druid.  Druid  only  can consume  a scalar value from each field. Therefore the jq expression has to return a scalar value.  The current jq parser implementation blindly picks the first element, and ignore the rest [here](https://github.com/apache/druid/blob/8296123d895db7d06bc4517db5e767afb7862b83/core/src/main/java/org/apache/druid/java/util/common/parsers/JSONFlattenerMaker.java#L99).   To solve your problem Druid needs a minor fix. The object flattening has to be applied at object level, then loop thru each object, and apply field level extractions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, but not easy.

I was in a similar situation, except the multi-record documents were in Kafka, not HTTP. Ultimately, the easiest solution was to change the format of the data going in, and you've made it clear that's not an option for you.

Batching support does seem to exist:
https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/4373

Gian, one of the main committers for Druid said in 2019:
https://github.com/apache/druid/issues/4373#issuecomment-489819616

> However, at present, you do need to implement a custom extension to
> get it (none of the builtin parsers will split out messages into
> multiple rows). I expect we will add that functionality at some point,
> but have not yet.

It looks like the solution is to write your own extension. A sample extension can be found here:
https://github.com/implydata/druid-example-extension

I know that's not a great solution, and it sounds like it might be possible in the future, so I'd keep an eye on releases as they come out.